# how to edit file/image on Update form Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have a form edit, and this form have data file/image.
I want to edit this but I don't know what to do. 
I cant display this file/image and can't edit this.

```
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="file_scan">
        File Scan Sertifikat
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="file_scan" type="file" class="form-control @error('file_scan') is-invalid @enderror" name="file_scan" value="{{pelatihan->file_scan}}" required autocomplete="file_scan">

        @error('file_scan')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show first this file ( by name I think) and I can edit. What's wrong?

UPDATE I add my controller :

```
  public function edit_pelatihan($id)
{
    $pelatihan = Master_seminar_pelatihan::findOrFail($id);
    if (!$pelatihan)
    abort(404);


    return view('admin/edit/edit_pelatihan', ['pelatihan'=>$pelatihan]);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "can't edit this"? The input file will get nothing even if you set the value with your current image name

Comment: if i update data like name : this name will changed , but how about image ? i dont know what next

Comment: learn about resource controller

Comment: Please attach your controller, so we could see it

Comment: So, what happened when the edit view accessed? You need explain more than this

Comment: try this one

return view('admin/edit/edit_pelatihan', compact('pelatihan'));